# Woocommerce how to display products which has two categories, one of them should be common

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing custom Woo shop theme. I want to display in front-page.php NEW COLLECTION products, it should be one block, and inside few smaller blocks with products ant their another vcategories, because, they will have common category NEW and another category depends BEDROOM/BATHROOM/CLOTHING, for now i have reahced display by one category.

```
<div class="col-md-12 row">
            <?php  
                $args = array(
                    'post_type'      => 'product',
                    'posts_per_page' => 4,
                    'product_cat'    => 'clothing'
                );
                
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    global $product;
                    $colors = explode(',',$product->get_attribute('color'));
                    $price = $product->get_price_html();
                ?>
                <div class="col-md-3 d-flex flex-column">
                    <div class="homepage__single-product">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
                            <p class="homapage__single-product-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                            <p class="homapage__single-product-price"><?php echo $price ?></p>
                            <p class="homepage__single-product-color">
                                <?php foreach ($colors as $color) {
                                        echo '<span class="attribute-color '. strtolower(trim($color)) .'"></span>';
                                    }    
                                ?>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </div> 
                </div>

                <?php

                endwhile;

                wp_reset_query();
            ?>
        </div>
```

I hope that my question will be clear, i am adding image with design for better understanding. I think that it should be somethimg like this code, but this code should have NEW as product_cat in $args, and then inside loop somehow do same block but with other categories.

[design shows how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHGya.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tax_query` to get products from multiple categories. check below code.

```
<div class="col-md-12 row">
    <?php  
        
        $prod_categories = array( 'bedroom', 'bathrooms', 'clothing'); //category slugs
        
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
        );
        
        if (!empty($prod_categories)) {
            $args['tax_query'] = array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $prod_categories,
                    'operator' => 'IN',
            ));
        }

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            global $product;
            $colors = explode(',',$product->get_attribute('color'));
            $price = $product->get_price_html();
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-3 d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="homepage__single-product">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
                    <p class="homapage__single-product-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                    <p class="homapage__single-product-price"><?php echo $price ?></p>
                    <p class="homepage__single-product-color">
                        <?php foreach ($colors as $color) {
                                echo '<span class="attribute-color '. strtolower(trim($color)) .'"></span>';
                            }    
                        ?>
                    </p>
                </a>
            </div> 
        </div>

        <?php

        endwhile;

        wp_reset_query();
    ?>
</div>
```